# Get the content of title tag from a webpage through .swf file

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I need to call the title tag from a web page using a flash banner.
I want to use the title tag as the content for the banner.

I am looking into flash.external.ExternalInterface.call, but am struggling with how to call getElementsbyTagName through this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `getElementsByTag` or `getElementById`, you can just use `document.title`.

This should do the trick:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
    var title:String = ExternalInterface.call("document.title");
}
```

Comment: @Dylan, did this work for you?  If so, consider accepting the answer as it helps future visitors